# Spring MVC : Binding 3 dropdowns to a date property in Controller for a form

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, binding

How should I implement a Controller that combines value from three dropdowns (date, month, year) to a single Date property and save it in a Datetime field in a MySQL database?